# How do I trigger a click on an input using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a button defined as

```
<input id="contractor-submit" type="submit" value="Send" onmouseup="formSubmit12(14)" style="display:none;">
```

I wan't to click this button using jQuery when another button is clicked.
How can I do this?
I've tried 
`jQuery('#contractor-submit').click();` 
and
 `jQuery('#contractor-submit').trigger('click');`

but it hasn't worked. I'm thinking it's because it has a 'onmouseup' but not 100% sure.

Comment: something like this `$("#contractor-submit").click()` should work. What is the `onmouseup` for?

Comment: Why are you using `onmouseup` in the first place? (But yes, triggering a `click` wouldn't cause a `mouseup`.)

Comment: Any console error? Have you bound click event from jQuery on that button? Because I am not seeing any onClick event.

Comment: did you include the jquery ?

Comment: @nnnnnn There's some validation going on. That input is generated by a form builder extension. When I unhide #contractor-submit and click the button I see data in the database. But when I click the button I created and then simulate a click on #contractor-submit nothing shows up in the database.

Comment: button is  rendered after DOm load like dynamic button  ?

Comment: @JYoThI function formSubmit12 is calling document.sfgForm12.submit. I tried calling this directly after my button is clicked and console print out "document.sfgForm12.submit is not a function"

Comment: Have you written an event handler for the click event on this button? Just triggering the event doesn't work. Also, is this button rendered in the browser, on page load?

Comment: @altoids Tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what are you planning to do but if just to click then trigger the mouseup maybe something like this.

```
$("#contractor-submit").click(function() {
  $('#contractor-submit').mouseup();
});
```

Or do you mean to place the cursor to the input after clicking other buttons?

```
$("#otherbutton").click(function() {
    var element = $("#contractor-submit");
    element.selectionStart = 0;
    element.focus();
}
```

I did not test this btw..

Answer (score 0):

Try with `mouseup` event like this.

```
jQuery('#contractor-submit').mouseup();
```

Wrap the script under `body`.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/w3zLL4my/)

Answer (score 0):

use native `click()`

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{

  $("#submit").click(function()
  {
  
     $("#contractor-submit").click();
  
  });


  $("#contractor-submit").click(function()
  {
    
    alert("hidden button clicked ");
    formSubmit12(14);

  });
  
  function formSubmit12(s)
  {
     alert("fom sumit12 called ");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="contractor-submit" type="submit" value="Send"  style="display:none;">

<input type="submit" id="submit" name="ss" value="submit" />
```